# Is there a way to avoid duplicates in a picker

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, android-sqlite

I'm creating an app for listing books that I own and want.. this app has a Sqlite Database. Each book has a row with columns ID, Author and Title. My issue is when i'm adding a new book I wanted to give this user the option to type in a new author name or get one from the picker. The picker ItemsSource is coming from the Authors column. My problem is because each author can have more then one book, the authors names are showing multiple times in the picker

### Xaml

```xml
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Entry x:Name="authorName" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Text="{Binding Author}"
       Keyboard="Text" 
       StyleClass="entry"/>

    <StackLayout>
        <Button x:Name="PickAuthor" Text="..." WidthRequest="40"
        Clicked="PickAuthor_Clicked"/>
    </StackLayout>

    <Picker x:Name="ExistingAuthors"
            Title="Select Author"
            IsVisible="False"
            SelectedIndexChanged="ExistingAuthors_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Picker.ItemDisplayBinding>
            <Binding Path="Author" />
        </Picker.ItemDisplayBinding>
    </Picker>
</StackLayout>
```

### Code Behind

```cs
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    await _connection.CreateTableAsync<WishList>();
    var book = await _connection.Table<WishList>().ToListAsync();
    _book = new ObservableCollection<WishList>(book);
    base.OnAppearing();
}

private void PickAuthor_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExistingAuthors.ItemsSource = _book.Distinct().ToList();
    ExistingAuthors.Focus();
}

private void ExistingAuthors_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    authorName.Text = ExistingAuthors.Items[ExistingAuthors.SelectedIndex];
}
```

I don't want the picker to displace duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove duplicates from a list you can use Linq.  The method below groups the collection by the duplicate field and selects the first group.

```
private void PickAuthor_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ExistingAuthors.ItemsSource = _book.GroupBy(b => b.Author)    // group by Author
                                       .Select(g => g.First())    // select first group
                                       .ToList();
    ExistingAuthors.Focus();
}
```

This will return a list of your entity type.

Answer (score 0):

If you're only displaying the list of Authors, select the `Authors` from `_book`, then call `Distinct` to remove duplicate author names.

```
private void PickAuthor_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    ExistingAuthors.ItemsSource = _book.Select(x => x.Author.Trim()).Distinct().ToList();
    ExistingAuthors.Focus();
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't seem to want to work. The picker is still pulling duplicates. maybe a bug in Xamarin?

Comment: I updated the answer to include `.Trim()` which will remove any whitespace. This is also not case sensitive, so if the list contains "Maverick" and "maverick", both capitalized and uncapitalized names will appear on the list.

Comment: When i add a break point at  ExistingAuthors.ItemsSource = _book.Select(x => x.Author).Distinct().ToList(); it shows me that the Distinct is working..

Comment: How are you assigning `ExistingAuthors.ItemsSource` before the button click?

Comment: in the button click

Comment: Now when i use that code I'm getting this weird error,, I can't figure it out. Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

Comment: Ya, that code works as i watch it in break mode. but it throws that error i post when it finishes executing. very weird

Comment: You could loop through distinct authors and manually add them one by one to the picker

Comment: I'm just not under standing that error i keep getting.. for some reason it keeps crashing when I use _book.Select(x => x.Author.Trim()).Distinct().ToList(): But if I just pass in the _book it works just has doubles